# how to implement a crowdsale using the current version of openzeppelin 4.X

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, crowdsale

I develop smart contracts and I really like to use openzeppelin libraries for this, I know how to implement ICO using Crowdsale.sol contract from openzeppelin, but there is no such contract in the latest version of the library, how can I implement a sale of tokens using the current version of the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Crowdsale contract (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol) from OZ is not too outdated. It's from some 2,5 years ago, but the language hasn't changed too much. So you should be able to modify it quite easily to compile with modern versions. Or, if you wish, you can just write your own and use the OZ version as reference.

If I remember right, OZ removed the contract because crowdsales stopped being popular and it was an effort to maintain the contract. I think that still holds true - there isn't much need nor demand for direct crowdsale contracts. I recommend you to research more about Initial Liquidity Offering or something else.